# TypeScript/WebPack compiler not processing SCSS files

Tags: typescript, sass

I am building an NPM package that includes React components. Each React component has its own SCSS module. (component.module.scss) I have created a custom typings.d.ts file that includes the following declaration.

```js
declare module '*.scss' {
    const content: { [className: string]: string };
    export default content;
}
```

I have included this in my TSCONFIG:

```js
"include": [
    "src",
    "*.scss",
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
```

I can run `tsc -p .` without errors and the `lib` folder is output with the compiled JavaScript and type definitions. When I run my Webpack task I can an error `Can't resolve './sample.module.scss'`.

Shouldn't the typescript compiler be processing my SCSS files and creating TypeScript modules from them? What am I missing?

Here is my webpack config.

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: {
    'component-library': './lib/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: "./bundle.js"  // in /dist
},
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", "jsx", ".scss"]
},
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }
      ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: !isDevelopment
  },
  output: {
    filename: () => {
      return !isDevelopment ? '[name].[hash].min.js' : '[name].js';
    },
    hashDigestLength: 10,
    libraryTarget: 'amd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  }
});
```

Comment: This is usually the responsibility of a bundler (like Webpack) and not TypeScript's `tsc` command to compile your application. Are you using something like Create React App to build your components?

Comment: I guess webpack also suggested you to add a loader for scss file. Did you see that?

Comment: Can you share your bundler/webpack config?

Comment: I added my webpack.config to the initial question.

Comment: I did not use create-react-app or any other tooling to scaffold this project. I am wanting to create a reusable package that shares common code for several of my projects (internal to org).

Comment: After some trial and error and I have learned that if I copy my scss files into ./lib folder where the typescript compiler pushes files, it processes the SCSS files just find an includes them in the bundle. Do I really need to compile the TypeScript, copy the SCSS and then run webpack?

Comment: @Kameron did you resolve this issue?